# Handle JWT expiration in SolrJ client side

Tags: jwt, solrj, solrcloud, clientcredential

Currently I am setting the JWT token(client_credentials) in the header while creating the connection to solr in java. The token is expiring in 15 mins and need to recreate the connection changing the header.

Is there a better way to refresh the solr connection with the updated token in Java automatically ?

```
      Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
      List<Header> headers = new ArrayList();
      headers.add(header);
      httpClientBuilder.setDefaultHeaders(headers);
      CloseableHttpClient httpClient =  httpClientBuilder.build();
```